# Number theory/calculus/algebra etc. equivalents of Euclid's Elements?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, elementary-number-theory, book-recommendation

Anybody know any books that tackle mathematical topics in a deductive, axiomatic structure akin to Euclid's Elements? Thanks.

Comment: You may be interested in Bourbaki - or Principia Mathematica

Comment: You have a choice of which axioms you want to start from. Many advanced calculus books, for example Spivak's calculus, treat the subject starting from axioms for the real numbers. Some will start instead from Peano's axioms for the natural numbers; along the way they will derive the axioms for real numbers.

Comment: Disquisitiones Arithmeticae for the Number Theory.